# メンバー変数がローカルで参照できない

Tags: typescript

ionicでtypeScriptを書いていますが、メンバー変数で宣言したindexNameに値を格納使用とするとコンパイルエラーが出てしまいます

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  title = '指標サマリ';
  // var obj;
  index = [
    '日経平均',
    'TOPIX',
    'マザーズ',
    'REIT'
  ];
  //ここでindexNameを宣言
  indexName = new Array(7);


  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

  }
  bar() {
    const req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        if (this.response) {

          var obj = JSON.parse(this.response);
          console.log(obj[0].name);
          for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
            // 下のindexNameでエラー
            indexName[i]=obj[i].name;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    req.open("GET", "http://localhost:3000/records");
    req.responseType = "text";
    req.send();
  }
}
```

Comment: ぱっと見では `this` を忘れているようです。が、問題の箇所はメソッド直下ではなく `function` の中のようなので `this` では無く、別の方法でインスタンスを参照する必要があります。典型的にはメソッド直下で `const self = this` などとしておいて `function` の中では `self` で参照します。あるいは `const indexName = this.indexName` としておけば、`function` 内はいじらずに済みます（手元に環境が無く再現していませんので、あくまで参考に）。

Comment: 解決しました！ありがとうございます！